# Oracle Sql to attribute with namespace

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to add attribute to xml using Oracle sql statement. XML is stored as data in a column in table 'item'. I have no issue adding a new 'id' attribute with value '123' as given in below query.

```
UPDATE item SET item_xml = INSERTCHILDXML(item_xml , '/item','@id', '123') where customer_id = '1';
```

However if i add xml namespace and instead of regular 'id' attribute if I want to append namespace like 'xml:id' below xml throws error '**Invalid XPATH expression**', please let me know what is the way to avoid throwing this error

```
UPDATE item SET item_xml = INSERTCHILDXML(item_xml , '/item','@xml:id', '123') where customer_id = '1';
```

I understand we do not use namespace in ordinary cases however I have given 'id' attribute as an example & since our application generates xml which is consumed in other system that requires attributes with namespace for few of the attributes.

After updating xml should look some thing like below, please assume attribute 'xml:id="123"' is NOT present initially in the xml clob of the table 'item' .

```
<items>
  <item xml:id="123">Apple</item>
<items>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a new item with that ID (in which case where does 'Apple' come from?), or add the attribute to an existing item? Including your starting XML for that customer might be helpful. Based on your result, your first update won't actually do anything.

Comment: I am adding "id" attribute to existing xml to 'item' element. The 'Apple' is the value of the element 'item'. So the xpath will be "/items/item". First query will work after correct xpath which is '/items/item' nevertheless as soon as you add namespace '@xml:id' query will start throwing error which is real issue i am need solution to it. In case of incorrect of xpath either the attribute will not set but it will not give 'Invalid XPATH expression'.

Comment: Oh... are you really still on Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is supported.

You could use a `modify` XPath to do it; with the side effect that the namespace declaration appears in the attribute, even if it's already declared within the document; which hopefully won't concern your downstream system:

```sql
UPDATE item SET item_xml = XMLQuery('
  copy $n := .
  modify (  
    for $i in $n/items/item[$item][not(@xml:id)]
      return insert node attribute xml:id {$id} into $i
    )
  return $n'
  passing item_xml, 'Apple' as "item", 123 as "id"
  returning content
)
where customer_id = 1;
```

```
ITEM_XML
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<items>
  <item xml:id="123" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">Apple</item>
</items>
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb70168aaf34f25963875fa759fae99c)

I've passed in the item value and ID value as parameters rather than hard-coding them in the XPath; depending on where and how you link those things, you might be able to do a single update for all your rows, getting the item/ID mapping from another table.

This works in later versions of Oracle, [e.g. 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb70168aaf34f25963875fa759fae99c), and should work from 11.2.0.3 I believe. It won't work in earlier versions though, so if you're really on 10g then it will need a different approach.

Comment: Thank you much Alex, is there any way that it can prevent adding attribute xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace". I see it is added along with xml:id attribute. Should i have to execute one more query to remove it redundant "xmlns:xml" attribute? or it can be suppress, if at all?

Comment: Not that I can see, it's being added internally and doesn't appear controllable. You could, I suppose, remove it from the final XML/CLOB with `replace()` but that's a bit of a pain.

Comment: Thank you  Alex!!